# Does In App Billing v3 support subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I want to make sure that from Google services the "In App Billing v3" service supports subscriptions.

From the documentation in Google

> The In-app Billing Version 3 service only supports managed in-app products, so make sure that you specify that the purchase type is 'Managed' when you add new items to your product list in the Developer Console.

[The link where is the documentation where I read that.](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html)

In case that "App Billing v3" does not support subscriptions, which are the alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: yes it does support that. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: yes, it does support subscription. The reference is to the fact that it doesn't support Unmanaged purchase type which was available in v2.